# Rails google map javascript, only show one point and delete one mark point when other point was click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-markers

i use code in this example

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 35.687719, lng: 139.702146 }
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    window.event = e;
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
 });
}

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
  
  map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwqIkJwBb6g4KirOaLnNgE1I6MtWnKxac&callback=initMap&language=ja">
</script>
```

Now, i want to show only one point in map by lng, lat.
And when i click one new point in map, i want to remove marker for old point in map to ensure only show one point.
Can you help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var map;
var gmarkers = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 35.687719, lng: 139.702146 }
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    removeMarkers();
    window.event = e;
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
 });
}

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
  
  map.panTo(latLng);
  gmarkers.push(marker);
}
 
function removeMarkers() {
  for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwqIkJwBb6g4KirOaLnNgE1I6MtWnKxac&callback=initMap&language=ja">
</script>
```

Comment: thanks you @Borra
`removeMarkers` method is exactly that i need

Comment: @Borra
i want to use gg map in edit form. so i move gg map to show in modal.
Get lat and long from DB, click button and use lat, long to initMap in modal, choose other point and pass new lat, long to form
can you support me ?

Comment: Can you update your code in JSfiddle or in Stackoverflow. So we can complete that.